# Are EDX and DX the same register?

Tags: assembly, x86

Sorry for the ignorant question, but I'm rather confused about x86.

Is EDX essentially the same register as DX?
I understand EDX is 32 bit while DX is 16 bit.

If I move 0x1 to EDX would 0x1 also be in DX?

Comment: How they could be the same register if `dx` is 16 bits and `edx` is 32 bits? 16 bits can't be 32 bits and vice versa.

Comment: As an aside, when instructions are encoded, the encoding for EDX in 32-bit mode and for DX in 16-bit mode is the same. The machine language bytes for `mov dx,1` and `mov edx,1` are identical. If you want to use dx in 32-bit code or vice vesra, that would make assembler emit a slightly different command (with a bitness-override prefix).

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev In 64-bit code (x86-64) these instructions are encoded the same way as in 32-bit code. However, in 16-bit code `mov dx,1` is `ba 01 00`, but in 32-bit and 64-bit code `mov edx,1` is `ba 01 00 00 00`, so the opcode is the same (`ba`), but the immediate value is a 32-bit value instead of a 16-bit value. In 32-bit and 64-bit code `mov dx,1` is encoded as `66 ba 01 00`.

Comment: Good point; I picked a wrong command to demonstrate. `mov [e]dx, [e]ax` is a better example.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

DX is simply the lower 16b of EDX :)

```
mov EDX, 0x1;         --> DX = 0x1
mov EDX, 0x12345678; --> DX = 0x5678
```

Answer (score 22):

```
[76543210 76543210 76543210 76543210 76543210 76543210 76543210 76543210] bits
[                                  RDX                                  ]
                                    [                EDX                ]                 
                                                      [       DX        ]
                                                      [  DH    ][   DL  ]
```

Answer (score 4):

Also, if you're on a 64 bit system, EDX is the low 32 bit of the RDX register, which is a 64 bit register.

Comment: However, modifying `edx` will always zero the high 32 bits of `rdx`. This is completely different comparing to the relationship between `edx` and `dx`, for example, where you can modify the low part of the `edx` using `dx` as dest, without affecting the high 16 bits of `edx`. There is no way to change only the low 32 bits (`edx`) of 64-bit general purpose registers, such as `rdx`. The only way to keep 64-bits registers' top 32 bits as is is to use only the entire 64-bit register (`rdx`) or its 16-bit (`dx`) or 8-bit (`dl`, `dh`) 'subregisters' as dest, but not the 32-bit 'subregister' (`edx`).

Answer (score 1):

You could think of it as pointers:

```
long theRealRDX;
long *     rdx = &theRealRDX;
int  *     edx = (int*)&theRealRDX;
short int * dx = (short int*)&theRealRDX;
char *      dl = (char*)&theRealRDX;
```

except for high part erasure mentioned in nrz comment

Comment: And remember that Intel is little endian :-)

Comment: it's not really a pointer, so it doesn't matter that it's little-endian.